# Floated items and div displaying differently in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm working on CSS and HTML to try understand position and floats. I have been able to successfully create a layout structure without any problem. However, I have noticed that when I use the Compatibility mode in IE 9, the look of the page changes. This is especially true in terms of padding in the H1 and the Footer div. I tried setting div and margins to 0 for the footer element and also the floated divs, but no luck.

I know there are bugs in the older version of IE, however, I wonder if there is something simple I'm missing here that could solve that.

Below is my HTML and CSS code, and images from IE 9.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testing.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="leftnav">LeftNav</div>
        <div id="rightnav">RightNav</div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hereunder is the CSS:

```
#container
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    border: 1px solid black;
}


#leftnav
{
    float:left;
    width:160px;
    display:inline;
}

#rightnav
{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:5px;
}

#footer
{
    clear:both;
}
```

I appreciate any pointers into this.

**Note**: I couldn't post the images into this message directly - stackoverflow restricts new users from posting images as spam prevention.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to fix these issues in comptability mode? are you using a CSS Reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line to the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
```

It tells internet explorer to always render in a way that is supported.